# Tried Java reflection's ".getDeclaredField" method but still meet "NoSuchFieldException"

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying modification of an instance's fields through Java reflection.

Here is my original code.

```
        for(Field f: customerClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println(customerClass.getDeclaredField("firstName"));

        for(int i=0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(columnNames[i]);
            field = customerClass.getDeclaredField(columnNames[i]);
            field.setAccessible(true);
```

And the results.

```
private java.lang.String Customer.firstName
private java.lang.String Customer.lastName

private java.lang.String Customer.firstName
"firstName"
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: "firstName"
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
```

I am wondering why "customerClass.getDeclaredField("firstName")" works, but "customerClass.getDeclaredField(columnNames[i])" throws an Exception, since columnNames[0] == "firstName".

Comment: No images of code, or error messages, please.  It makes it impossible for others to copy/paste your code into their IDEs to help debug it.  Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: `println(columnNames[i])` prints `"firstName"`, which is an 11-character string, when it should have printed the 9-character string `firstName`, without the double-quotes. `"firstName"` != `firstName`, or in Java string literal terms `"\"firstName\""` != `"firstName"`

Answer (score 2):

If you'll look at your output for `columnNames[0]`, you'll see that it's not `firstName`, it's `"firstName"`.  Remove the quotes and it should work.